# When using Terraform, why does my RDS instance tear down and stand back up when I make a change to an EC2 Instance in its in/egress rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I have an ec2 resource (shown) with its own security group (not shown)

```
resource "aws_instance" "outpost" {
  ami           = "ami-0469d1xxxxxxxx"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name      = module.secretsmanager.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [module.ec2_security_group.security_group_id]
  subnet_id              = module.vpc.public_subnets[0]
  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.env}-${var.user}-ec2-outpost"
    Terraform   = "true"
    Environment = var.env
    Created     = "${timestamp()}"
  }
}
```

A security group for an RDS instance that has ingress and egress rules for that ec2's security group:

```
module "db_security_group" {
  source      = "terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws"
  version     = "~> 4"
  name        = "${var.env}-${var.user}-${local.db_name}"
  vpc_id      = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress_with_source_security_group_id = [
    {
      rule                     = "postgresql-tcp"
      source_security_group_id = module.ec2_security_group.security_group_id
    }
  ]

  egress_with_source_security_group_id = [
    {
      rule                     = "postgresql-tcp"
      source_security_group_id = module.ec2_security_group.security_group_id
    }
  ]

}
```

And the RDS instance that is in `db_security_group`

```
module "rds" {
  source                                = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"
  version                               = "~> 3.4.0"
  identifier                            = "${var.env}-${var.user}-${local.db_name}"
  engine                                = var.postgres.engine
  engine_version                        = var.postgres.engine_version
  family                                = var.postgres.family
  major_engine_version                  = var.postgres.major_engine_version
  instance_class                        = var.postgres.instance_class
  allocated_storage                     = var.postgres.allocated_storage
  max_allocated_storage                 = var.postgres.max_allocated_storage
  storage_encrypted                     = var.postgres.storage_encrypted
  name                                  = var.postgres.name
  username                              = var.postgres.username
  password                              = var.rds_password
  port                                  = var.postgres.port
  multi_az                              = var.postgres.multi_az
  subnet_ids                            = module.vpc.private_subnets
  vpc_security_group_ids                = [module.db_security_group.security_group_id]
  maintenance_window                    = var.postgres.maintenance_window
  backup_window                         = var.postgres.backup_window
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports       = var.postgres.enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports
  backup_retention_period               = var.postgres.backup_retention_period
  skip_final_snapshot                   = var.postgres.skip_final_snapshot
  deletion_protection                   = var.postgres.deletion_protection
  performance_insights_enabled          = var.postgres.performance_insights_enabled
  performance_insights_retention_period = var.postgres.performance_insights_retention_period
  create_monitoring_role                = var.postgres.create_monitoring_role
  monitoring_role_name                  = "${var.env}-${var.user}-${var.postgres.monitoring_role_name}"
  monitoring_interval                   = var.postgres.monitoring_interval
  snapshot_identifier                   = var.postgres.snapshot_identifier
}
```

When I change something with the ec2 instance (like, say, `iam_instance_profile`) or anything about instances referenced in the in/outbound rules for `module.db_security_group.security_group_id`, why does does the RDS instance get destroyed and recreated by Terraform?

Comment: Can you show the plan output? What exactly forces replacement?

Comment: How can I focus on the "what forces replacement" aspect of the plan when I am pasting it in here?

Comment: Plan should indicate what gets changed and results in the replacement.

Comment: Okay I will check and post shortly @marcin. But the rds has changed quite often in my plan over the development, when I change other resources. Is this unexpected generally?

Comment: Yes, its strange why security group would lead to replacement. Maybe something else triggers the replacement? The plan should show that.

Comment: @Marcin see my answer.  since I am providing a `snapshot_identifier` I need to not provide `username` and `password`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in addition to the `username` and `password` behavior seen when `snapshot_identifier` is given ([here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17712#issuecomment-783445624) and [here)](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17722), Terraform will also mark the RDS instance for deletion and recreation when either of these parameters is set.  You will see this happening when re-`apply`ing the plan in question, because the initial `username` and/or `password` is never actually set by Terraform; it thinks there is a change.